# Express-session not set cookies in the browser after deploying the server application on the Heroku platform

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, backend, express-session

I faced the issue with express-session and I have tried to solve it.

Here is what I found some solutions.
https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/633

But honestly to say it doesn't work for me.

When I run a server on my local machine everything works fine and the cookie set and contained in the browser.
But I have no idea why after deploying on the Heroku platform the cookie option not set and not contained in the browser.

Configuration

```
import {DB_HOST} from "./configs/database";
import {PORT} from "./configs";
import session from "express-session";
import mongoDBSession from 'connect-mongodb-session'


//Session db
const DBSessions = mongoDBSession(session)


//Create express app
const app = express();
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))

//Config Object to Avoid Deprecation Warnings
const dbOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
};

//MongoDB
//Connection database
mongoose.connect(DB_HOST, dbOptions);

//Store Connection Object
const db = mongoose.connection;

//Connection events
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB database...");
}).on("error", (err: string) => {
    console.log(err);
});


//Store session
const sessionStore = new DBSessions({
    uri: DB_HOST,
    collection: 'sessions'
})

//https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/633
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(routesArray,
    session({
        secret: SESSION,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
            sameSite: false,
            maxAge: MAX_AGE,
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: true
        }
    })
)


//Starting server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?